# Are you able to use number values as variables that can be called upon in Luau?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

Im wondering if you would be able to use a number value as a variable that can be used in multiple different scripts

Answer (score 1):

If the variable, or it's parent, is global, sure.

If you need to pass the variable e.g. to functions, then you would need to make a table containing that value. Because in case of a table you pass the reference instead of a copy.

For example in it's simplest form:

```lua
local yourValue = {value = 0}

local function test(v)
    v.value = 5
end

print(v.value)
```

Out of scope for this question, but you could enhance this value object with metatables.

Specifically for Roblox, take a look at the [NumberValue](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/NumberValue) or similar, which is basically the above.